# How to group rows while omitting null values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table that's like this

```
ID | FieldA | FieldB | FieldC | GroupID
---------------------------------------
 1 |     50 |    NULL|     80 |      1
 2 |   NULL |     60 |   NULL |      1
 3 |     70 |    NULL|     50 |      1
```

I want to produce a single row that shows Non-NULL values in a descending order (by ID)
So the resulting table would look like this

```
ID | FieldA | FieldB | FieldC | GroupID
---------------------------------------
 3 |     70 |      60|     50 |       1
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?
I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (table)
GROUP BY GroupID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

But no luck (of course)

Here's a fiddle, so you can play w/ this quickly!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71846f/2

Thank you!

Comment: If I get you right, you want to select from each column the largest value which is not larger than the value you selected for the previous column?

Comment: Hey Andreas, value size is irrelevant. the largest ID matters though.

Comment: So, in words, I want values from the highest ID (which is 3 in my sample table), but because its FieldB is NULL, it borrows the value from the next highest ID, 2, and sets FieldB as 60

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not possible without sub queries for each column:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT `ID` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ID`,
(SELECT `FieldA` FROM `table1` WHERE `FieldA` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `FieldA`,
(SELECT `FieldB` FROM `table1` WHERE `FieldB` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `FieldB`,
(SELECT `FieldC` FROM `table1` WHERE `FieldC` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `FieldC`,
(SELECT `GroupID` FROM `table1` WHERE `GroupID` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `GroupID`
```

Comment: Hi Uril, this produced the desired result(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bccf27/1). However, is there a simpler solution to this? In my actual table, I have 20 some columns, and I'm concerned with the performance :/

Answer (score 0):

You should null check your field like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE FieldA is not null
AND   FieldB is not null
AND   FieldC is not null
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: What would be the result with OP's sample table?

Comment: None. But see his output where fields are non null.

Comment: Isnt that obvious because you are saying "Non-NULL values in a descending order (by ID)" So in each row you have null value? Is your requirement non null still valid? or are you looking for something like SELECT max(id) id, max(fieldA) fieldA, max(fieldB) fieldB, max(fieldC) fieldC, max(groupID) groupID
FROM test

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(feA),
       MAX(feB),
       MAX(feC) 
from test05
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by only Group ID and then select the max of all the coulmns. .
Which will help

```
SELECT max(id),max(FIELDA),max(FIELDB),max(FIELDC),GroupID
FROM (table)
GROUP BY GroupID
```

Comment: this would result answer to become: 70, 60, 80. which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

As you want mininum value for FIELDC this there for you just want this.
This query is not tested
Please reply if any error comes for this query

```
SELECT max(id),max(FIELDA),max(FIELDB),min(FIELDC),GroupID
FROM (test)
GROUP BY GroupID
```

Comment: @mode Please check i have paste the answer

Comment: This is the same as an existing answer and the OP has already said this doesn't give the required results

Comment: @m0dE Please check the fiddel demo sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71846f/21

Comment: Have you checked o/p is 3 |     70 |      60|     50 |       1 which is the desired o/p

Answer (score 0):

You can create CTE with column name 1-20.(copy into it the original data)

then you will select each column (max(column)) and update it into temp table .

(copy the original table into temp and truncate it) .

do it with loop on column_number and dynamic sql.

i hope you understand what i mean -:)